# aws ses - emails not getting stored in s3 but getting received on Workmail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Can someone please help me, I am trying to store incoming mails to my domain @mydomain.com  to s3 , I have followed the procedures mentioned in [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-action-s3.html)
,

created a workmail with the domain @mydomain.com  , and I am able to send and recieve from verified_mail@mydomain.com  from workmail, but it's not getting stored in s3.

Is there a way to debug the complete flow when I send mail to verified_mail@my_domain.com .
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the response , it seems that my policy was getting saved in a non active policy , got this figured out and mails are getting saved to s3 bucket now.